# How to query json attributes with a space using json_extract_scalar function w/o 'INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path' error?

Tags: sql, presto

json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$.campaign id')--threw error
json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$."campaign id"')--threw error
json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$.""campaign id""')--threw error
json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$."campaign id"')--threw error
json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$.["campaign id"]')--threw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove a dot between `$` and `[`.

```
json_extract_scalar(eventprops,'$["campaign id"]')
```